# Does Subpartition in Oracle hinder partition performance

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am doing a research on partitions and got to a bit of a dead end on the subpartition topic.

Here is what I found out in the oracle manual (https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14231/partiti.htm):

“The partitions of a range-list partitioned table are logical structures only, as their data is stored in the segments of their subpartitions. The list subpartitions have the same characteristics as list partitions. You can specify a default subpartition, just as you specify a default partition for list partitioning.”

So, first of all, I conclude that since subpartition have their own "segment", they have their own file. Am I correct?

Secondly, I wonder if that hinders partition effectiveness. Here is what I mean:

If we have a partition, most often it is on a single tablespace & file (please correct me if I'm wrong, I don't even know if it is possible to spread it on a several tablespaces/files). This means that when we search specifically in the partition, it will look through only one file.

Then again, if subpartition is realized through several segments(files) and even in several Tablespaces, doesn't it mean that when we query the partition (not the subpartition) it would take more time (relatively) ?

Lastly, I don't have the time, nor the possibility to test this theory, and that's why I'm asking. The end of my project is near (completely my fault) and I can't really test partitioning on my company's server.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no direct relationship between segments and files. Segments are allocated space from a tablespace, which is composed of one or more files. The number of files accessed is not a significant factor in performance.

Comment: Some more on that from the docs: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e40540/physical.htm#CNCPT1389

Answer (score 1):

Actually term `SUBPARTITION` is a bit misleading, because it anticipates that you have a "PARTITION inside a PARTITION". For some operations (e.g. `DROP PARTITION`) this is true, but for other operations this is not the case, e.g. you cannot run `ALTER INDEX ... REBUILD PARTITION` if the table has SUBPARTITIONS.

Consider a `PARTITION` to be determined by **one** attribute, either `RANGE` or `LIST` or `INTERVAL` or `HASH`

A `SUBPARTITION` is basically the same but determined by **two** attributes  of `RANGE`, `LIST`, `INTERVAL` or `HASH`.

In terms of performance or physical storage there is no difference between partitions and subpartitions.